# Generate QR Code from base64 String Siwft 4

Tags: swift, base64, qr-code

I am trying to create a VCard and then convert it into a QR code. Everything is working perfectly fine until I add a base64 Photo string in VCard. In this case, the QR Code generation fails due to the size of the string. I tried a few hacks but nothing seems to work.

Below is my code for generating VCard with QR Code.

```
 func textBasedVCard()-> Data?{
    var string = "BEGIN:VCARD\nVERSION:3.0\n"
    string += "FN:\(self.firstnameTextField.text!)\nN:\(self.lastnameTextField.text!)\nORG:\(self.companyTextField.text!)\nTITLE:\(self.titleTextField.text!)\nTEL;TYPE=WORK,VOICE:\(self.phoneNumberTextField.text!)\nADR;TYPE=WORK:;;\(self.adressTextField.text!)\nPOSTALCODE:\(self.postcodeTextField.text!)\nCITY:\(self.cityTextField.text!)\nitem3.URL:\(self.linkedinTextField.text!)\nitem4.URL:\(self.twitterTextField.text!)\nEMAIL;TYPE=PREF,INTERNET:\(self.emailAdressTextField.text!)\nPHOTO;ENCODING=BASE64;TYPE=JPEG:\(self.base64ImageString)\nEND:VCARD"
    let utf8str = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    if let base64Encoded = utf8str?.base64EncodedString(options: .init(rawValue: 0))
   
    {
        self.generateQRCode(string: string)
        return Data(base64Encoded: base64Encoded)!
    }
    return nil
}

 func generateQRCode(string: String) {
    if qrcodeImage == nil {
        
        let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii, allowLossyConversion: false)
        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator")
        filter?.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
        filter?.setValue("Q", forKey: "inputCorrectionLevel")
        
        qrcodeImage = filter?.outputImage

        let context:CIContext = CIContext.init(options: nil)
        let cgImage:CGImage = context.createCGImage(qrcodeImage, from: qrcodeImage.extent)!
        let image:UIImage = UIImage.init(cgImage: cgImage)
        
        self.imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)! as NSData
        print(imageData)
    }
}
```

This is the error

> Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

This error is on line cgImage in generateQRCode(). The reason is filter has nothing. i.e nil

If I remove Photo from VCard then evertyhting works fine.

Comment: What is the data size with the image included?

Comment: I guess the problem is with data size itself. Due to its size filter is not working. @Aris

Comment: @Aris Its says  (input data too big?)

Comment: Yes, I think that data length is too big, according to wikipedia the max length is 2,953

Comment: @Aris any solution or way around? I tried maximum options but still not working.

Comment: hmm.. Try with `inputCorrectionLevel` L

Comment: Nope. Data Size 8755 for L correction @Aris

Comment: Well, I don't think that it is possible to encode an image that big, since the max size should be 3k

Comment: @Aris any hack we can reduce it to 3k?

Comment: I am not even sure if 3k is the right amount, I would try to encode Base64 strings from 1 length until it stops working, so you can determine the max size then find a suitable image..